# object in javascript reference by this but not when using event listener

Tags: javascript, html, oop

Why is it that the `this` is not referencing the object, `myObject`?

When I do `console.log(this)` returns `undefined`... Why?

#### Javascript:

```
var myObject = {
                    
    product: document.getElementById('product'),
    
    button: document.getElementById('btn'),
    
    productView: function(){
        if (this.product.className === 'grid') {
            this.product.className = 'list';
        } else {
            this.product.className = 'grid';
        }
    },
    
    clickHandler: function(e) {
        var o = this;
        console.log(this);
        o.productView();
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    
    init: function (){
        this.button.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler, false);
    }
};

myObject.init();​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nAppk/1/)

Many Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: [JavaScript “this” keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.this` in your handler method for the event refers to the object being clicked. Use something like var `self = myObject;` and then use `self` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind `this` to the correct context of you object. I common way to achieve this is to assign a reference of the local `this` to another variable inside your init function:

```
init: function (){
    var that = this;
    this.button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {that.clickHandler(e)}, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `this.clickHandler()` there would set `this` to the object. However, you're merely passing the function to `addEventListener`, and the browser will set a custom `this` value when it calls the function.

If you want to bind the current `this` value, use `this.clickHandler.bind(this)`. The function returned by `bind` will also receive the "wrong" `this` value, but it calls `clickHandler` with the bound, correct `this` value.

Comment: `Function#bind` is a recent addition to ECMAScript and will not work in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

First just use 'this' for your click handler...

```
clickHandler: function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    this.productView();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Then you have a few options. Here are two...

**Option A:**

```
init: function (){
    var o = this;
    this.button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        o.clickHandler(e);
    }, false);
}
```

**Option B:**

```
init: function (){
    this.button.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler.bind(this), false);
}
```

I asked a related question about which of these options is preferrable: [When should a JavaScript reference object be used versus .bind()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25938496/1766230)